# SQL Server Changelog creation, Identity Syntax, and Invalid COlumns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design, triggers

I'm currently working on creating an SQL Server trigger, which after an update, should populate a change-log with any salary changes made, and by which user.

The changelog table that I made which should receive updates can be seen here:

```
CREATE TABLE ChangeLog
(
ChangeID int identity(1,1) primary key,
EmpID int,
[User] nvarchar(30),
[Date] smalldatetime,
OldRate money,
NewRate money
)
```

Everything is fine with table as far as I can tell, however when I go to create the trigger, i'm starting to receive a few errors (and a boatload of confusion.) I've tried researching several methods of doing a trigger that updates a different table with a new row, and as far as I can tell, the structure of it is correct, however I am unsure how I have messed up the contents.

```
CREATE TRIGGER payrate_change ON Employees FOR UPDATE
As
DECLARE @originalPay VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @newPay VARCHAR(100)
If UPDATE (PayRate)
BEGIN
SELECT @originalPay = (SELECT PayRate FROM deleted)
SELECT @newPay = (SELECT PayRate FROM inserted)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ChangeLog]
        (ChangeID, EmpID, [User], [Date], OldRate, NewRate)
    VALUES
        identity(1,1), 
        Employees.EmployeeID, 
        SUSER_SNAME(), 
        SYSDATETIME(), 
        @originalPay, 
        @newPay
    FROM inserted
END
```

The payrate portion of the two select statements give an error saying they are invalid columns, even though two lines above it calls PayRate just fine. Then for the values portion of the Insert Into statement, identity claims to have incorrect syntax despite me using it the exact same way in the creation of the table.

Does anyone have any ideas on what may be the issue with this trigger? Any input would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

After the suggested changes below, I re-added ChangeID (primary key) to the trigger, however now IDENTITY is giving me an incorrect syntax error:

```
CREATE TRIGGER payrate_change ON Employees FOR UPDATE
As

If UPDATE (PayRate)
BEGIN

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ChangeLog]
        (ChangeID, EmpID, [User], [Date], OldRate, NewRate)
    select
        IDENTITY(1,1),
        i.EmployeeID, 
        SUSER_SNAME(), 
        SYSDATETIME(), 
        d.PayRate, 
        i.PayRate
    FROM inserted i
    JOIN deleted d on i.EmployeeID = d.deleted
END
```

EDIT2: Adding the final result for anyone who is interested:

```
CREATE TRIGGER payrate_change2 ON Employees FOR UPDATE
AS

If UPDATE (Pay)
BEGIN

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ChangeLog]
        (EmpID, [User], [Date], OldRate, NewRate)
    select
        i.EmployeeID, 
        SUSER_SNAME(), 
        SYSDATETIME(), 
        d.Pay, 
        i.Pay
    FROM inserted i
    JOIN deleted d on i.EmployeeID = d.EmployeeID
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ommit the identity column and it will be populated on its own

Your trigger doesn't handle multirow updates, take a look at [Best Practice: Coding SQL Server triggers for multi-row operations](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/best-practice-coding-sql-server-triggers)

You can JOIN deleted and inserted pseudo tables, I assume EmployeeID is the key?

Try this

```
CREATE TRIGGER payrate_change ON Employees FOR UPDATE
As

If UPDATE (PayRate)
BEGIN

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ChangeLog]
        (EmpID, [User], [Date], OldRate, NewRate)
    select
        i.EmployeeID, 
        SUSER_SNAME(), 
        SYSDATETIME(), 
        d.PayRate, 
        i.PayRate
    FROM inserted i
    JOIN deleted d on i.EmployeeID = d.deleted
END
```

Also be aware that `If UPDATE (PayRate)` will fire even if you do something like `SET PayRate = PayRate`  So you probably want to check if the value actually has changed, you can add that in the JOIN between insertyed and deleted and also make sure to check for NULLS

Comment: Actually the ChangeID was what I intended to have as the primary key since this will be updating a changelog where there could be multiple of the same employee ID's. I tried adding ChangeID on afterwards since PayRate was still throwing up an "invalid column" error and I've come up with what i've now added to the original post. Am I doing the identity statement incorrectly in some way? I thought this was the way to do it correctly but it seems to still throw an error saying incorrect syntax.

Comment: ChangeID will be auto generated since it is an identity column..ommit it

Comment: Ok thank you for the quick response. Do you have any idea why PayRate and deleted are still showing as invalid column name? The error it displays is: "Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure payrate_change, Line 4
Invalid column name 'PayRate'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure payrate_change, Line 16
Invalid column name 'deleted'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure payrate_change, Line 13
Invalid column name 'PayRate'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure payrate_change, Line 14
Invalid column name 'PayRate'.
"

Comment: Does the Employees table have a PayRate column?

Comment: I did a double check, and I apparently called it Pay rather than PayRate. Thank you so much for your help.